# Sorting data vector for a histogram using ggplot and R

Tags: r, vector, ggplot2, histogram, montecarlo

So I have 10.000 values in a vector from a Monte Carlo simulation. I want to plot this data as a *histogram* and a *density plot*. Doing this with the `hist()` function is easy, and it will calculate the frequency of the of the different values automatically. My ambition is however doing this in `ggplot`.

My biggest problem right now is how to transform the data so `ggplot` can handle it. I would like my x-axis to show the "price" while the x-axis shows the frequency or density. My data has a lot decimals as shown in the example data below.

`myData <- c(266.8997, 271.5137, 225.4786, 223.3533, 258.1245, 199.5601, 234.2341, 231.7850, 260.2091, 184.5102, 272.8287, 203.7482, 212.5140, 220.9094, 221.2627, 236.3224)`

My current code using the `hist()`-function, and the plot is shown below.

```
hist(myData,
 xlab ="Price",
 prob=TRUE)
lines(density(myData))
```

[Histogram for the data vector containing 10000 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25aS6.jpg)

How would you sort the data, and how would you do this with `ggplot`? I am thinking if I should round the numbers as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say exactly without seeing a sample of your data, but have you tried:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(Price)) + geom_histogram()
```

or:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(Price)) + geom_density()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! My data is right now a long vector, e.g.

`myData <- c(266.8997, 271.5137, 225.4786, 223.3533, 258.1245, 199.5601, 234.2341, 231.7850, 260.2091, 184.5102, 272.8287, 203.7482, 212.5140, 220.9094, 221.2627, 236.3224)`

I assume I need to convert the vector to a `data.frame()` to use your code? How can I do this if all the data is in one row?

Comment: `myData <- data.frame(price = c(266.8997, 271.5137, 225.4786, 223.3533, 258.1245, 199.5601, 234.2341, 231.7850, 260.2091, 184.5102, 272.8287, 203.7482, 212.5140, 220.9094, 221.2627, 236.3224))`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I got it to work now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
ggplot() +
   geom_bar(aes(myData)) +
   geom_density(aes(myData))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This plotted the data, but after converting the vector to a data.frame, the result was much better.